# Загрузка файлов в laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Как в laravel загружать файлы?
Уже пробовал кучу разных способов, не в какую не получается.
Имеется html код

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="file" name="image">
<button type="submit">Отп</button>
</form>
```

и код контроллера

```
if($request->image!= '') {
    $set->image= $request->image;
    File::put($request->image, $request->image);
}
```

Где моя ошибка? Направьте на правильный путь. Спасибо.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#files

Comment: Перед тем как задать этот вопрос я тщательно просмотрел документацию.

Comment: И все равно непонятно как делается, пытался через Storage но создается пустой файл.

Comment: И откуда именно из документации вы взяли этот код? Что за переменная `$set`? В документации явно не используется такая проверка: `$request->image!= ''`.

Comment: этого не хватает `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Answer (score 8):

В форму нужно **добавить `enctype="multipart/form-data"`**, что бы разрешить загрузку файлов

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image">
<button type="submit">Отп</button>
</form>
```

Далее создаем контроллер:

```
public function fileUpload(Request $request){

    if($request->isMethod('post')){

        if($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $file->move(public_path() . '/path','filename.img');
        }
     }
   }
```

Где, `

- $request->hasFile('image')` - проверка на существование файла, в качестве аргумента указываем идентификатор поля
- `$file = $request->file('image')` - запись объекта файла в переменную
- `$file-move(public_path() . '/path','filename.img')` - метод для перемещения файла в нужную нам директорию, 1-й аргумент указывает директорию в которую нужно сохранить файл, 2-й указывает новое имя файла
- `public_path()` - возвратит нам полный путь к директории public

Answer (score 1):

Вам в комментариях все верно говорят. В документации все подробно написано. Но судя по тому, что вы написали в примере, вам бы стоило начать с изучения основ самого PHP. Откуда вы взяли поле image в классе Request? Где вы такое нашли? В документации черным по белым написано `$file = $request->file('image');`
Что за переменная `$set`? Но ваш код по идее ломается еще даже не доходя до него. 
Вам не помешает узнать, как смотреть логи в Laravel, да и вообще как дебажить PHP-приложения. Хотя бы с обычным `var_dump()` для начала. В общем рановато вам еще в Laravel. Как минимум прочитайте внимательно документацию и поймите, что там написано.

Answer (score 0):

Есть готовая реализация для тех, кто использует Ларавел. Пакет называется UploadImage. Есть статья на русском: [Гибкая загрузка изображений в Ларавел](https://cleverman.org/post/37)